# Providing consistency in front of login without session

Tags: java, spring, security

I work on an xml based spring application which uses Spring 3.2 . Now, we are developing an application in front of login which makes the app open to attacks. 
I want to know when app flows that the data which is taken from previous page is consistent with the next one. I mean i don' t want doubt that my data is changed by someone.
Can you suggest me any secure ways to provide this? I don' t keep any session which worries me.
P.S.The project doesn' t use Spring Security and i don' t know if i can use it.

Thanks all of suggestions.

Comment: Can you give more details ? Do you put the data previous page , if so  how do you transport that data next page  ignoring attack issue?

Comment: For approval i use data and call web service once, and if service response okey, i get to the next page transporting the same data and finalize process. So i have to be sure this approval data and final data is same, I mean nobody was in middle. So i want to provide this and don' t know how to do without session.

Comment: if you call web service in server side code, you can keep approval data in cookie as encrypted. So you can decrypt the data to compare with web service response.

Comment: thank you, i'm going to do this way i guess.

Comment: @magirtopcu i can' t keep the key to decrypt . i' m stucked ..

Comment: so you should give more details and maybe you look these links: https://spring.io/blog/2014/01/20/exploiting-encrypted-cookies-for-fun-and-profit,  http://www.code2learn.com/2011/06/encryption-and-decryption-of-data-using.html  , or you can search with keywords like "spring cookie encrypt, decrypt" on google.